# For adding an object in set, is it necessary to override equals and hashcode both.?

Tags: java, data-structures, equals, hashcode, hashset

Recently an interviewer asked me that I have a class where I have overriden its `equals()` method but have not overridden my `hashCode()` method.

Now is it necessary to override my `hashCode()` method too.?

What will happen if i don't override my hashcode method, will set maintain its unique property of not allowing duplicates.?

The question is all about internal implementation of `Set` and here my confusion is if two objects return different `hashCode()`, according to me their `equals()` won't be checked and then the unique property of `Set` will be violated if the two objects came out to be equal.

Is that true.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to understand this is to see hashcodes as buckets.When you store objects in sets they go to these buckets according to their calculated hashcode.

When you override equals , that is one object is equal to another, so they should land in the same bucket.

However that won't be the case since you haven't overriden the hashcode method to ensure this.

So jvm will try to search the object in the wrong bucket. won't find it and as a result you'll have duplicates.
(btw my interviews are starting soon as well , really scared!)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the concrete [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object))-implementation, as mentioned by the [Collection doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (Collection is the super-class of Set)

> (The Object.hashCode() specification guarantees that two objects with
>   unequal hash codes cannot be equal.) More generally, **implementations
>   of the various Collections Framework interfaces are free to take
>   advantage of the specified behavior** of underlying Object methods
>   wherever the implementor deems it appropriate.

So, for instance the [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) (as the name suggests) will use the hash value, other implementations of [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) may not - and only ever use `equals()`

finally some good advise from the [Object.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) doc:

> Note that **it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden**, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

Answer (score 1):

You should always override both. They are part of a contract.

Look at the java docs and make sure you fulfil the details there. 
Eclipse can also generate these methods for you.

Answer (score 0):

Both are always recommended.

E.g. If you have super Class `Person` with properties `id,`, `name`, `surname` and you define `equals` and `hashCode` based on `name` and `surname` and a concrete sub Class `Contact Person` with extra properties like `email`, it's important to define new `equals` and `hashCode` for your Class `Contact Person`. If your Concrete Class `Contact Person` implements an entity having the `email` property as a unique field, redefining `equals` and `hashCode` based only on `email` would be enough. Though, defining a new `equals` and `hashCode` based on `name`, `surname`, and `email` is better.